# Asp.net Mvc Display template of String, but now every simple type wants to use it!

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I created a Display Template which when passed a string renders a disabled text box

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<String>" %>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model, new { disabled = "disabled" })%>
```

Which works great.  However, for some reason MVC wants to try and stuff DateTimes and Ints through it as well, which is throwing exceptions

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.String'.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the name of the physical ascx file and what code are you using to invoke it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to strongly type the template to a String.

you can try something like this :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<%= Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
             , new { disabled = "disabled" }) %>
```

And in your view you call it like this

```
Html.DisplayModelFor(model => mode.name);
```

For more information see an example of the default built-in editor template for the string in [Brad Wilson](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/) [**article**](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html) in his his series on Templates in ASP.NET MVC.

You should consider going through the complete series. I can't express how helpful this series was for me.