# EditorFor - The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.String'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I can't seem to figure out why this wouldn't work. I'm using ASP.NET MVC2 and I'm simply trying to override the default editor appearance by placing this code into /Shared/EditorTemplates/String.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<string>" %>
<%=Html.TextBox(null, Model, new { @class="Text" }) %>
```

Then in my View page, I have this line which is of type Int32:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.AppID) %>
```

For some reason, this results in the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.String'.
```

I don't see how anything could be wrong on my end, it's pretty simple. Why does it try to use the editor for a string if the type is an Int32? I also should mention that I've overridden the Editor for a bool? type (to render boolean values as a checkbox) and it works just fine on the same page.

**EDIT**

Well I searched many times, but I didn't see this post until I found it in the "Related" links. I suppose this will work, I still think it's a confusing and inconsistent implementation though:

[Asp.net Mvc Display template of String, but now every simple type wants to use it!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928134/asp-net-mvc-display-template-of-string-but-now-every-simple-type-wants-to-use-it)

Answer (score 3):

in kendo ui Grid do :

```
public class BookBean
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public Int32 Id { set; get; }

        public String Title { set; get; }

        public String Author { set; get; }

        public String Publisher { set; get; }

        [UIHint("Integer")]
        public Int32 Price { set; get; }

        [UIHint("Integer")]
        public Int32 Instore { set; get; }

        [UIHint("Integer")]
        public Int32 GroupId { get; set; }
    }
```

in Integer.ascx in Shared/EditorTemplate folder do :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<int?>" %>

<%: Html.Kendo().IntegerTextBoxFor(m => m)
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
      .Min(int.MinValue)
      .Max(int.MaxValue)
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your editor template you've told it to expect a `ViewUserControl<string>` but you're passing an `int` to your `EditorFor`.

Since the editor template is waiting for a `string`, and you're passing in an `int`, it wont work.

Comment: Ok, well I guess that's the confusing part to me. I thought it used reflection to choose the correct editor template. Is that not the case? Like I said, I have bool? template, and it renders boolean values correctly - it doesn't not call the string template.

Comment: Do you have a separate int template?

Comment: No, I don't. I wouldn't think that I would need one, because I first created the bool? template, and everything continued to work. Then I created the string template and this error occurred. Maybe I should just create the int template, but I may have many other types and I'd like it to use the default template for those so I don't have to generate unnecessary redundant templates.

Comment: Just for more detail - I tried to create the int template, but got the same error as long as I still had the string template around. Once I removed the string template, the error went away and it rendered properly. For some reason, the string editor template is always being chosen for int values.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this error, but with a DateTime. I was able to get things rolling again by changing the editor template to use `Object` as its model type.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with Int16 field although I have Integer template in the project, so i had to create a specific template for Int16 
FileName: Int16.cshtml
Html:

```
@model Int16?

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model)
```